# dig and nslookup results connection timeout for my subdomain.cloudns.nz using 8.8.8.8 as dns but it works for anything else or from somewhere else

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, nslookup, dig

when i run `dig @8.8.8.8 mysub.cloudns.nz`  i get this :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 mysub.cloudns.nz
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

but it works if i add `any` keyword as the type like this :

```
dig @8.8.8.8 mysub.cloudns.nz any
```

and it results like this :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 mysub.cloudns.nz any
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44306
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysub.cloudns.nz.      IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mysub.cloudns.nz.   3600    IN  SOA ns41.cloudns.net. support.cloudns.net. 2022051801 7200 1800 1209600 3600
mysub.cloudns.nz.   3600    IN  NS  ns42.cloudns.net.
mysub.cloudns.nz.   3600    IN  NS  ns43.cloudns.net.
mysub.cloudns.nz.   3600    IN  NS  ns41.cloudns.net.
mysub.cloudns.nz.   3600    IN  NS  ns44.cloudns.net.
mysub.cloudns.nz.   3600    IN  A   1.2.3.4

;; Query time: 407 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: چارشنبه مئی 18 13:12:12 +0430 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 193
```

it looks like this one works too:  `dig @8.8.8.8 mysub.cloudns.nz +tcp`

why am i getting timeout with first one then? the result is the same with nslookup too

note: it works with any other domain like google stuffs and anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with my isp `mtn irancell`. just checked from other friends laptop with the same isp and difference sim cards.
its alright in all other isps.

Comment: @Toto that is the author of the question answering his own question.

Comment: @music2myear what do you mean then? i don't get it

Comment: Toto added review feedback indicating you've made a comment. I informed them you were the one asking the question, so your answer, though light on details, was the actual solution to your problem. Toto then deleted his feedback, which is a correct thing to do.